# How to hide properties depending on access modifiers globally when serializing Json in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-6.0

I want to hide entity members where property access modifier have `virtual` in it. I think it is possible to do this with `JsonOptions` but I do not serialize the response myself.

How can I set `JsonOptions` for `System.Text.Json` globally in `Program.cs`?

```
public ActionResult<List<Announcement>> List() { //body }
```

In this example, I don't serialize it myself and it's the same for all of the endpoints I currently have. Since I can't return string here with custom serializer, I need to do it globally for `System.Text.Json`.

I could make a custom json options and custom converter, but I can not use it for my controllers and that is what I it need for.

Comment: "I could make a [..] custom converter, but I can not use it for controllers". You can. Just add the JsonConverter attribute to your data classes, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to

Comment: Use DTOs, not entity types for serialization.